# What is a single SQL query?

Tags: sql

If I use subqueries or nested queries in my answer, is it still a single SQL query?

Comment: Yes, it is a single MySQL query.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos: it's also a single Postgres query. Or a single Oracle query. Or a single DB2 query.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the term "query" is well-defined in SQL.  Colloquially, it generally refers to a `SELECT` statement that is executed to return a result set.  With this definition, subqueries are part of a single query.  This would tend to be what I would use.

When using set-based operations, sometimes people refer to the following as two queries:

```
select a.* from a
union all
select b.* from b;
```

In my opinion, that is being a bit sloppy with the terminology.  But I get the issue:  this "query" has two "select statements".

It gets more complicated if you consider transactions.  If you run multiple queries within a single transaction, then is it one "query" or more?  Consider:

```
begin transaction;
    update a set x = 1 where . . . ;
    update a set x = 2 where . . . ;
commit transaction;
```

Here it is really confusing.  The transaction has two `update` statements, but these don't take effect until the `commit` succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because although internally many queries will execute, the query will bring out a single result set.